# Where is a good place to buy food coloring in bulk?

Tags: shopping, coloring

We use a lot of food coloring, not so much for cooking but for activities with my little one. Do you know of a good place to buy food coloring in bulk (either in store or online)? It can be quite pricey at the grocery store.

Answer (score 2):

School art and craft supply outlets sell colourings safe for children's consumption in liquid and powder forms

Powder based colour works fine in many bakery products